# userform data filter, cancel if no data

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I am attempting to create a userform to filter/display data from a worksheet that meets the input criteria.
I have successfully entered a field for user name and a date range, however I can't figure out how to create a hard stop if there is no data to display.
for example the criteria is a username or date in which there is no data for, rather than filtering the data table and displaying nothing, I want the action canceled and I would probably have a msgbox pop up.

Here's the simple test code I put together so far, I do have it so that it doesn't filter if the field is left blank so that is not my issue.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim DataRange As Range
Set DataRange = Range("datatable1")
Sheets("data").Visible = True
Sheets("data").Select


 If ComboBox1.Value = "" Or ComboBox1.Value = Null Then
AutoFilter = False
Else: DataRange.AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:=ComboBox1.Value
End If

datefilter:
If TextBox1.Value = "" And TextBox2.Value = "" Then
AutoFilter = False
ElseIf TextBox2.Value = "" Then
DataRange.AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:=">=" & TextBox1.Value, Operator:=xlAnd
ElseIf TextBox1.Value = "" Then
DataRange.AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="<=" & TextBox2.Value, Operator:=xlAnd
 Else: DataRange.AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:=">=" & TextBox1.Value _
             , Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & TextBox2.Value

End If
Unload Me


End Sub
```

Really appreciate any assistance.

Comment: Just an idea to start with: Apply the filter first, then check if there is still visible data and use this to decide if you show the sheet 'data' or a msgbox instead.

Comment: @jochen, we think alike. That's pretty much what I coded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does what you want. It applies the non-blank filters and if no data is visible it turns the filters off and displays a message:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim DataRange As Range

Set DataRange = Sheets("data").Range("datatable1")
Sheets("data").Visible = True
Sheets("data").Select

If ComboBox1.Value <> "" Then
    DataRange.AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:=ComboBox1.Value
End If

If TextBox1.Value <> "" Then
    DataRange.AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:=">=" & TextBox1.Value
End If

If TextBox2.Value <> "" Then
    DataRange.AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="<=" & TextBox2.Value
End If

If DataRange.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count = 1 Then
    'turn off filter
    DataRange.AutoFilter
    MsgBox "No matching data"
End If
Unload Me
End Sub
```

EDIT: Modify to work with structured table (VBA ListObject)

After our discussion in comments it sounds to me like your data is in a stuctured table. You can confirm this by clicking a cell in your data. A Table Tools/Design tab will appear in your ribbon towards the right end. To the far left of the controls for that tab will be a box with the table name, in this case "DataTable1."

[image]

As you've noted, Excel automatically creates a range with that same name, however it only includes the data, not the header. My code above fails because a filter that returns nothing has no visible data cells, whereas if the headers are included it will have one row of visible cells, the header row.

The code below sets a reference to the whole table, applies the autofilter to it and checks whether there is only one visible row:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim loDataTable1 As ListObject

Set loDataTable1 = Sheets("data").ListObjects("DataTable1")
Sheets("data").Visible = True
Sheets("data").Select

If ComboBox1.Value <> "" Then
    loDataTable1.Range.AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:=ComboBox1.Value
End If

If TextBox1.Value <> "" Then
    loDataTable1.Range.AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:=">=" & TextBox1.Value '
End If

If TextBox2.Value <> "" Then
    loDataTable1.Range.AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="<=" & TextBox2.Value '
End If

If loDataTable1.ListColumns(1).Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count = 1 Then
    'turn off filter
    loDataTable1.Range.AutoFilter
    loDataTable1.ShowAutoFilter = True
    MsgBox "No matching data"
End If
Unload Me
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm getting the debugger popup and the message no cells were found.

Comment: What line? What is the address of datatable1? Does it include the headers?

Comment: line : *If DataRange.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count = 1 Then* I'm assuming it includes the headers when referring to the entire datatable but I'm unsure. I attempted to test it by filtering a date which is not found in the table.

Comment: Okay, I'm guessing that Datatable1 doesn't include headers, e.g., "date","name", etc. Is that correct?

Comment: There are headers to my data table, I meant I was unsure if the coding automatically includes it as I'm pretty amateur with vba

Comment: My code works (for me) if the range "DataTable1" includes the headers. If the range doesn't include the headers, then we need to tweak it. So far I can't tell if the range DataTable1 includes the headers. I do understand that your data has headers, but that's not what I'm asking.

Comment: I think it does not include the headers. I was mistaken in assuming that by setting my range "DataRange" as '.range("datatable1")' it was selecting the entire data table. But doing a simple '.select' I can see that it's only selecting the data and not the headers. Pretty new to VBA so please excuse me.

Comment: I manipulated it a bit as I've made several changes to the workbook (including losing all saved data and having to rebuild once ) since posting here but this works perfectly! I moved the sheet visibility to the end of the code and `exit sub` after the "no data found" msgbox so that it hard stops and requires the user to alter their search information. a question I do have is the control values. is the `.value <> " "` that you wrote, the same as `= null or = " "`?

Comment: I'm glad it works. Sorry about the data loss :-) `Null` isn't needed here. It's a value that you can assign to some variables to mean that it has no valid data. It wouldn't apply to a textbox. Please also note that the test in the code is `.Value <> ""`, not `.Value <> " "` as you typed in the comment. Yours would mean "a space" whereas the code is testing whether the Textbox or Combobox contains a blank. That's all you need to test for a blank.

Comment: Oh I see, thanks for the info. And yes, I just added those spaces in my reply, though I'm unsure why lol.